# Control-C sends control-alt-delete to my Ubuntu server over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sar, reboot

On my Ubuntu VM:

```
Linux xxxxxxx 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24
21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

to which I am connected over SSH, I am running this command:

```
sar 1 10000 | awk '{print $9}'  | grep -v aaaa
```

(strangely) this command doesn’t produce any output (why?) but next thing is even stranger. If I press Control-C while the command is running it is kind of sending Control-Alt-Delete to my server and the server reboots (why?).

```
root@xxxxxxx:~# sar 1 10000 | awk '{print $9}'  | grep -v aaaa
^Croot@xxxxxxx:~#
Broadcast message from root@xxxxxx 
       (unknown) at 12:01 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
Control-Alt-Delete pressed
```

thanks for your help.

Best regards
Jaor

Answer (score 0):

While described situation sounds quite unrealistic it is actually a fact and is caused by a bug in `systat`, `sadc` in particular. `sar` process spawns `sadc` process.

TL;DR - Interrupting `sar` before `sadc` completes it's job makes `sadc` triggering a reboot.

Solution to this is to update `sysstat` to a reasonably new version (the fix is from 2014). From the commit it seems this should be fixed in `systat` 12.1.7 (not sure about this - still this is a fix from over 5 years ago, understood ubuntu 14 is pretty old).
https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/commit/c3de69658006af0e0e3b7746e8646b8b4cdd2860

more details can be found here

http://northernmost.org/blog/sar-rebooting-ubuntu/index.html

UPDATE: as for no results - this is unrelated thing and is caused by the fact that `awk` by default is buffering it's input - to get results instantly it needs to be invoked as `awk -W interactive`